# When is it the case that a mem-initializer-id is not found by ordinary lookup in the constructor's class definition?

Tags: c++, c++11, language-lawyer

Given this snippet

```
class Base
{
public:
    Base(){};
};

class Derived : public Base
{
public:
    Derived();
};

Derived::Derived() :Base() {}
```

and considering this statement in §12.6.2/2 (my emphasis)

> In a *mem-initializer-id* an initial unqualified identifier is looked up
>   in the scope of the constructor’s class **and, if not found in that
>   scope**, it is looked up in the scope containing the constructor’s
>   definition.

I would you say that the lookup for the name `Base` in the definition of the `Derived` constructor **is** found in the `Derived` class definition.

I was just wondering, if there are other more tangible examples, other than the one given in 12.6.2/3, where a *mem-initializer-id* is not found in the constructor's class.

Comment: @AlanStokes It's an *injected-class-name*.

Comment: All that I'm saying is that the name `Base` is found by the usual lookup, in the `Derived` class definition.

Comment: What's the problem with the example in 12.6.2/3?

Comment: @T.C. Probably the OP thinks it's contrived. I voted to close as unclear.

Comment: @T.C. There's no problem. It seemed to me a little bit artificial. Was that the case that the statement which I reproduced above was written this way just to satisfy code like this in the example in 12.6.2/3, or are there other examples where the lookup for a mem-initializer-id is not found in the class constructor?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The *mem-initializer-id* must name the constructor’s class, a non-static data member of the
constructor’s class, or a direct or virtual base of that class. If it's an actual class name (whether the derived class or a base), it will be found as an *injected-class-name* inside the class's scope. If it's a data member, name lookup will obviously find it inside the class's scope. So that leaves a typedef, but that's also the example given in 12.6.2/3:

```
class Base { };

class Derived : public Base
{
public:
    Derived();
};

using BaseAlias = Base;

Derived::Derived() : BaseAlias() {}
```

Answer (score 0):

> *I was just wondering, if there are other more tangible examples, other than the one given in 12.6.2/3, where a mem-initializer-id is not found in the constructor's class.*

A little more practical example than the one using a simple alias with `typedef`/`using` for a base class from §12.6.2/p3:

```
#include <type_traits>

struct Base {};
struct Base2 {};

struct Derived : Base, Base2
{
    Derived();
};

using namespace std;

Derived::Derived() : conditional_t<true, Base, Base2>{} {}
//                   ~~~~~~~~~~~~^
```